# How to include an interaction with a quadratic term?

Tags: regression, interaction, quadratic-form

I want to predict $y$ with $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ and I suppose that $x_{2}$ has a quadratic effect on $y$ and that there is an interaction. How to model that?

I've look in [previous questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interaction+quadratic) but there seem to be different suggestions.

[1.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287006/interpreting-interactions-in-a-linear-model-vs-quadratic-model) Include all possible effects separately (see model 2):

$y$ ~ $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{2}^{2} +  x_{1} : x_{2} +  x_{1} : x_{2}^{2}$

[2.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384339/interpreting-interaction-with-quadratic-term) Keep all the parts of your polynomial variable together:

$y$ ~ $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{2}^{2} +  x_{1} : (x_{2} + x_{2}^{2})$

I use the notation of R where $y$ ~ $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{1} : x_{2}$, for example, means that there are two main effects, namely $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, and an interaction between $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$. In R there is no need to specify the intercept, but it is estimated by default, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same formula (meaning that the models are equivalent), just the R notation is different.

Here is an example with random data:

```
x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)
y <- x1 + x2 + x2**2 + x1*x2 + rnorm(100)

fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x2^2) + x1:x2 + x1:I(x2^2))

fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x2^2) + x1:(x2 + I(x2^2)))

fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x2*x2) + x1:(x2 + I(x2*x2)))
```

All three of these produce these same results where `x1` is interacted with both `x2` and the squared version of `x2`:

```
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.12678 -0.64983  0.03115  0.59760  2.26080 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -0.11838    0.12757  -0.928    0.356    
x1             0.95627    0.13901   6.879 6.61e-10 ***
x2             1.04394    0.09099  11.473  < 2e-16 ***
I(x2 * x2)     0.94417    0.06015  15.698  < 2e-16 ***
x1:x2          1.05098    0.12875   8.163 1.45e-12 ***
x1:I(x2 * x2)  0.05926    0.09656   0.614    0.541    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.003 on 94 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8412,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8328 
F-statistic: 99.59 on 5 and 94 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```